# Nginx redirect to requst url stripping index.php or index.html

Tags: nginx, web-server, configuration, http

I have a url:

```
http://devs.website.com.au/
```

Then if I put this url in browser

```
http://devs.website.com.au/index.php
```

I am redirecting it to

```
http://devs.website.com.au/
```

Which works fine using this code in nginx

```
if ( $request_uri ~ "/index.(php|html?)" ) {
  rewrite ^ /$1 permanent;
}
```

But what if I have this existing page:

```
http://devs.remotestaff.com.au/sample-page.php
```

Then I tried,

```
http://devs.remotestaff.com.au/sample-page.php/index.php
```

As expected it will redirect back to:

```
http://devs.website.com.au/
```

as defined in my nginx rule, is there a way where whenever nginx see index.php
or index.html at the end of the URL, it will redirect to the requested url without the index.php or index.html

So when I do: `http://devs.remotestaff.com.au/sample-page.php/index.php`

it should redirect to:

```
http://devs.remotestaff.com.au/sample-page.php/
```

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^(.*/)index\.(php|html?)$ $1 permanent;`

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks! It worked, one last thing, what if I want to exclude the rule everything under http://devs.website.com.au/portal/ ?

Comment: You could use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in the `if` statement's regular expression. But one wonders why your clients are presenting the wrong URI in the first place!

Comment: As Richard says, this feels like a bandaid to a different problem. Through rel canonical you can just tell search engines which URL you want to be indexed. Use that in sitemaps too. And try and have those served in the application in the first place.

Comment: Instead of `if`, I would suggest using regex matching in `location` blocks and making redirects inside it.